# Delete duplicate elements from custom data type vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I am trying to erase the duplicate vector elements. First I sort the elements and then look for duplicates. I overloaded the sort function but I am not sure how to overload for erasing part.

```
class cp_data
{
    public:
    int num;
    char name;
    cp_data(int a, char b)
    {
        num = a;
        name = b;
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<cp_data> data;
    cp_data data1(1, 'a');
    cp_data data2(2, 'b');
    cp_data data3(1, 'a');
    cp_data data4(2, 'b');
    data.push_back(data1);
    data.push_back(data2);
    data.push_back(data3);
    data.push_back(data4);
    std::sort( data.begin(), data.end(), []( const cp_data& lhs, const cp_data& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.num< rhs.num;
    });   
    data.erase(unique(data.begin(), data.end()), data.end());
    system("pause");
}
```

This code gives the following error.

> Error C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function 
>    Error    C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `unique` doesn't know how to compare to elements for equality. You did not provide an `operator==(const cp_data& lhs, const cp_data& rhs)` or similar, so `unique` has no idea what constitutes "equal" elements for you. This can be fixed easily with another lambda:

```
int main()
{
    // [...]
    auto lessThanLambda = []( const cp_data& lhs, const cp_data& rhs )
    {
        return lhs.num< rhs.num;
    };   

    std::sort( data.begin(), data.end(), lessThanLambda);

    auto equalLambda = [](const cp_data& lhs, const cp_data& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.num == rhs.num;
    }

    data.erase(unique(data.begin(), data.end(), equalLambda), data.end());
}
```

Comment: This works fine. Thanks. Is it compulsory to sort the vector? This example don't work if I do not sort the vector.

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat Basically, yes. The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) does not say this directly because it is not _required_ that your range is sorted - only that _equivalent elements are consecutive_ (which can be achieved easily by sorting). `unique` would work fine on the vector `5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2` (leaving you with `5, 1, 4, 2`), but usually you will just call `sort` first.